# How to prevent other elements from aligning right when one element is floated left?

Tags: html, css, css-float

**[EDIT]** Thanks to [herkulano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341595/how-to-prevent-other-elements-from-aligning-right-when-one-element-is-floated-lef/7341847#7341847) and [GerManson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341595/how-to-prevent-other-elements-from-aligning-right-when-one-element-is-floated-lef/7341695#7341695) whose fixes worked for me.

But I am unable to decide which is better, reliable and cross-browser compatible? "overflow" or "clearfix:? Please help me with this, and I am good to go.

---

If my question is not clear, it will be, now. Just read on please...

(I am trying to display some thumbnails in php and these are the respective codes I am using.)

**1.** The following is the CSS code that I am using:

```
#gallerythumbnailsx { margin: 10px; }
#gallerythumbnailsx .gallery-item { float: left; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; }
#gallerythumbnailsx img { border: 2px solid #cfcfcf; margin-left: 5px; }
#gallerythumbnailsx .gallery-caption { margin-left: 0; }
```

**2.** related php code used is:

```
<div id="gallerythumbnailsx"><?php echo show_all_thumbs(); ?></div>
<p>Aahan is great!</p>
```

**3.** This is how the resultant HTML is displayed:

```
<div id="gallerythumbnailsx">
    <dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon">
            <a href="http://example.com/"><img width="100" height="75" src="http://example.com/xxx.jpg"></a>
        </dt>
    </dl>

    <dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon">
            <a href="http://example.com/"><img width="100" height="75" src="http://example.com/xxx1.jpg"></a>
        </dt>
    </dl>

    <dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon">
            <a href="http://example.com/"><img width="100" height="75" src="http://example.com/xxx3.jpg"></a>
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this is how it is being displayed ([screenshot](http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/9/24919230724-orig.jpg)). The issue as you can see, is that the text "Aahan is great!" is being pushed to the right of the thumbnails since I use `float: left` for thumbnails in the CSS. I want the text in a new line.

Answer (score 2):

add `p{clear:left;}` to your CSS

[awesome article explaining all floats](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/)

Added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex4CW/1/) for you

This uses the existing CSS (well it ignores the `#gallerythumbnailsx .gallery-caption { margin-left: 0; }` and `#gallerythumbnailsx .gallery-item { float: left; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; }` since I don't see why you would need em.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I want to make changes only to the given css ids/elements. I hope I am clear.

Comment: updated my answer with a example where you use only the existing css

Comment: Really sorry again. Please see my edits to the question. I am more clear now (I think). Thanks.

Comment: In that case, check GerManson's solution

Comment: It worked. But I am concerned about two things now. (1) Is it compatible in all browsers, even IE6? (2) What is `overflow: auto;` actually doing? I mean, from description of overflow's auto parameter "it adds a scroll-bar to see the rest of the content." (He didn't answer, so I am asking you.)

Comment: It means that if the content is clipped (by setting a fixed height/width on the `id="gallerythumbnailsx"`) scrollbars will be displayed. If no size is set, scrollbars are never shown

Comment: I think thats up to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373544/clearfix-vs-overflow

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it, hopefully

```
#gallerythumbnailsx { margin: 10px; overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: It worked. But I am concerned about two things now. (1) Is it compatible in all browsers, even IE6? (2) What is `overflow: auto;` actually doing? I mean, from description of overflow's auto parameter "it adds a scroll-bar to see the rest of the content."

Comment: it grows the container div as if the float elements where in the flow of the content.  When the div has a defined fixed height and the content grows beyond that, it adds a scrollbar.

Comment: Now, which in your opinion is better? The "clearfix" class method that [herkulano suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341595/how-to-prevent-other-elements-from-aligning-right-when-one-element-is-floated-lef/7341847#7341847) or the `overflow: auto;` one? I repeat, reliability and cross-browser compatibility (even IE6/IE7) is my priority. Thanks.

Comment: I think that is up to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373544/clearfix-vs-overflow

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the clearfix method on #gallerythumbnailsx it is cross-browser and this way you can reuse it elsewhere, just add the clearfix class where you use floats.

I made a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XhRk6/

The .clearfix util class was taken from: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: You mean clearfix works on every browser (IE6,7,8,9; Opera, Safari, Firefox and Chrome - including older versions)?

Comment: My theme already has css for `clearfix:after` so I didn't add any extra css (not even `clearfix:before` etc) and just added the class to the div and it worked. But as @GerManson suggested `overflow: auto;` also worked. Which do you think is better?

Comment: clearfix is better, just because it is non modern cross-browser, this includes ie6/7.