# Why HTML5 BoilerPlate, Blueprint and 960.gs CSS framework use Clearfix over overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css

Why HTML5 BoilerPlate, Blueprint and 960.gs CSS framework use `Clearfix` over `overflow:hidden`?

Why `overflow:hidden` is not preferred? To use `clearfix` every-time I need to add `clearfix` class to html element but I can add `overflow:hidden` to the element in css without modifiying  html.

Please explain with example the disadvantage to use `overflow:hidden`

Is `clearfix` class not mixing the presentation with content?

Comment: do you mean HTML5 boilerplate?

Comment: @OldCode101 yes I mistakenly wrote HTML4

Comment: I found an nice answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373544/clearfix-vs-overflow

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason the .clearfix-class doesn't just contain overflow: hidden; is because in some cases you *do not want* overflow set to hidden but you still want the element to clear itself.

Regarding using class="clearfix" all over your HTML I definitely agree that it's "mixing the presentation with content".

Personally I use SASS to avoid having to use classes for everything. With a SASS mixin I can simply go:

```
#foo {
    @include clearfix;
}
```

And still have the benefit of changing all my clearfix styling from one place.

Answer (score 2):

Well let me answer your question with a question (and then answer them).

**Q: Why do we use classes in CSS?**

A: To allow us to create re-usable code.

**Q: Well thats great and all, but how does it apply to this situation?**

A: When the next browser engine is released (probably IE breaking everything again) and your overflow:hidden no longer works you will have to go in and change every instance you created using it. Whereas if you were using the class all you have to do is update the code in one place, and voila everything works.

**tl;dr;**  future-proofing.

Comment: No browser is going to break something as fundamental as `overflow: hidden`. Your answer makes no sense.

Comment: Never? its hard to write certainties with intangibles.

Comment: The behaviour is defined in the CSS specs, it's not some magical hack. Read this: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/.